# ¿Cómo utilizar la misma base de datos en dos proyectos mvc 5 utilizando Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Recientemente he creado un proyecto mvc 5 utilizando Entity Framework CodeFirst y todo funciona correctamente, ahora necesito crear otro proyecto mvc 5 de la misma forma utilizando Entity Framework pero que este utilice la base de datos creada por el primer proyecto, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto de tal forma que los dos proyectos funcionen correctamente?

Answer (score 2):

En tu caso yo haría cualquiera de estas dos cosas:

1. Clic derecho al proyecto Agregar elemento existente y copiar los archivos del entity del otro proyecto.   Poner la conexión en el app.config o web.config, y agregar la referencias del entity framework.
2. Clic derecho Agregar Nuevo Elemento, selecciono Datos>Ado.net entity data model. Generar desde la BD. siguiente. Nueva conexión. Selecciono los valores de conexión. Siguiente.  Selecciona las tablas. Y crear el nuevo modelo de entity con el asistente seleccionado el origen desde una BD existente.

Mira en este ejemplo genera el modelo del entity desde una BD existente:
https://nicolocodev.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/primera-aplicacion-con-entity-framework/

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo haría es crear un nuevo proyecto de tipo librería, al cual muevo todos las entidades y el Context; y este proyecto lo añado como referencia al primer proyecto, así como también al segundo proyecto e incluirle la cadena de conexión. Para que no haya errores me aseguro de que tengo referencia a Entity Framework en los tres proyectos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaría creando el segundo proyecto como DataBase First. Se supone que el primero ya creo el modelo de datos. Y el segundo solo la va a usar. Eso si confirmaría que no este activa la migración automática para garantizar que no haya cambios inesperados en la base de datos que puedan afectar el segundo proyecto.